# calculating the scale factor for visual odometry

Tags: camera, scale, camera-calibration

I am implementing Avi's a visual odometry algorithm for a monocular camera from [this](https://avisingh599.github.io/vision/monocular-vo/). In this algorithm, he used the KITTI data set that comes with a text file to read the scale factor in each frame.

I would like to use the same algorithm on my camera but I don't know to compute the scale factor. 
Does anybody have an idea how to do that?

Thanks
Ola

Answer (score 0):

When it is presented that the algorithm is using 5 point algorithm, it's simply a motion estimate from 2D to 2D.

A 2D to 2D motion estimate decomposes the essential matrix into rotation and translation. But, on the other side, it suffers from scale uncertainty.  For this purpose, you need to calculate the relative scale in the ever incremental state.

Scale uncertainty can be calculated from the following ways:
1. calculating the distance ratio using two 3D triangulated points.
2. Trifocal constraint